# How to describe a matrix with a mathematical notation or a terminology?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. If $A$ has a nonzero $\ell \times \ell$ submatrix, $1\leq \ell \leq n$, the other entries are $0$, then how to describe the matrix $A$ with a mathematical notation or a terminology?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

I have a new idea: Whether there exsit permutation matrices $P$, $Q$ such that 
\begin{align*}
PAQ=\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $B$ is the nonzero submatrix.

Have any idea, please guide me.

Comment: You could describe the underlying map as being the direct product of some other map (that is, the one represented by the nonzero submatrix) with the zero map. It's a bit unwieldy, though.

Comment: Are you familiar with the block submatrix notation, e.g. $A = \begin{pmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which locates a (possibly) nonzero submatrix $B$ of $A$ in the upper left corner?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I know. I want to know the case that the nonzero submatrix $B$ which locates possibly arbitrary place, not necessarily in the upper left corner of $A$.

Comment: @ Patrick Stevens Please you look this topic again and give me some advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: @hardmath Whether there exsit permutation matrices $P$, $Q$ such that 
\begin{align*}
PAQ=\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $B$ is the nonzero submatrix.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of A is $m\times n$ and the order of the submatrix is $p\times q$ and the submatrix starts at $A_{ab}$,
$$
A_{ij}=0\;\forall (i,j)\in(\{1,2,..,m\}\setminus\{a,a+1,a+p-1\})\times(\{1,2,..,n\}\setminus\{b,b+1,b+q-1\})
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. But  I think that the form you give is  not good.

Comment: @bing It's not good but that's the deal with general stuff. If you can locate a good place to put your non-zero submatrix, someone might come up with a better form.

Comment: @ Jack's wasted life  I apologize to you. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @bing I do not accept your apology since it wasn't needed in the first place.Cheers.. :D

Comment: @ Jack's wasted life Whether there exsit permutation matrices $P$, $Q$ such that 
\begin{align*}
PAQ=\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $B$ is the nonzero submatrix.